# Android Studio: Is there a way to see all the files executed in real-time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio and I was wondering if there is a way to see what file/script is executed when I press a button in the Virtual Phone. Is it even possible?

I have a big project I did a long time ago and don't remember in what file the code is written. I need to find a way to show in what directory is located.

Example:
**Press Search Button**
- Show directory where that action is located.
"app/src/search/search-bar.java"

Answer (score 0):

For that, you must have to go through **AndroidManifest.xml** file to check which **Activity** is **launcher Activity**.

Then go in the **source file(.java)** of launcher Activity, from there you can find a way to check where it will go by discovering any **Intent**.

**The best way is to debug your project by putting breakpoints.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see such information in the logcat at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Android Profiler` available in `Android Studio 3.0` or higher. You can access it from **View > Tool Windows > Android Profiler**.

This will give you all the required information, You can see the Activities name which is running in the mobile. You can even track your **CPU, Memory and network** usages with this tool.

Sample:
[image]

Read more about [Android Profiler here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)